# Casting a const void * to a const char * in C

Tags: c, casting, qsort

So I have a C function that goes like this:

```
int cmp (const void *a, const void* b)
 return rot13cmp( (const char*)a, (const char*)b );
}
```

and rot13cmp is another function that takes two parameters of type const char *.

I pass this function into the compare parameter for the C [qsort](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm) function but it doesn't seem to work.

However, if I instead cast the const void * variables by doing

```
return rot13cmp ( *(const char **)a, *(const char **)b );
```

the function then starts to work. I looked this up at SO but every source said that the first method of casting should work so I wanted to know why only the second one worked for me?

Edit: Here's the relevant code I have,

```
int cmp (const void *a, const void *b) {
 return rot13cmp( (const char *)a, (const char *)b );
}

int rot13cmp (const char *a, const char *b) {
 while (*a == *b && *a != '\n') {
  a++;
  b++;
 }

 if (*a == *b) { return 0; }
 else if (*a == '\n') { return 1; }
 else if (*b == '\n') { return 1; }
 else { return rot13(*a) - rot13(*b);
}
```

and rot13 returns an int for the ASCII code of a letter rotated by 13 letters in the alphabet.

I called qsort by doing

```
qsort(words, word_count, sizeof(char*), cmp);
```

where words is an array of char** and word_count is an int. cmp is also just

Comment: I feel like an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) would *really* help here.

Comment: There must be a different reason for this to happen.

Comment: So how did you call `qsort()`?

Comment: We can't know anything about that if you don't show us what type your `a` and `b` have originally. From what you describe I'd guess they are pointers to pointers, but without information this is pure guessing.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added the relevant code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`qsort()` calls the comparison function with pointers to the array elements that should be compared.

If your array contains `const char*`, that means the comparison function is called with pointers to those pointers, and you have to cast and dereference accordingly.

With `(const char*)a` you are interpreting the parameter as if it would be a pointer to `const char`. But it isn't. In reality it's a pointer to the `const char*` in the input array.

That's why `(const char**)a` is the correct cast, it interprets the parameter as a pointer to a `const char*`. To do string comparison you want that pointed-to `const char*`, which you access by dereferencing the casted value with `*`.

You can think of it as first correcting the type (by casting), and then accessing the pointed-to value (by dereferencing).

The difference between the two attempts is that the second case does an additional dereference. This is important since `qsort()` doesn't pass the  `const char*` directly, but rather passes a pointer to it. So we have to look at the pointed-to value to find what we are looking for. By casting directly to `const char*` we just claim that the variable would contain such a pointer, which won't end well because that's not the case.

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate on this?

I thought that both (char*) and *(char **) were valid ways to cast / dereference but I was wondering why the latter one worked.

Comment: *(char **) is dereferencing the pointer you are passing in, while (char *) is just a cast.

Comment: @ChangLiu: I added more details.